# Setting session expire time - Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have a web page that uses session variables. How can i set an expire time for a session? eg: after 15 minutes of inactivity , have to destroy the session.

I tried in config/session.js , but in vain.

As i am new to sails.js , please suggest how to achieve this.

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

It should work with

```
module.exports.session = {
  // ...
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 15*60*1000
  }
}
```

in your `config/session.js`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When i gave the following command , the sails server got down after the given expiry time.                           cookie: {
        secure: true,
        maxAge: 1200000, // 1200,000 ms = 20 min
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 1200000) // 1200,000 ms = 15 min
     },

Comment: This is the error iam getting :TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
    at exports.parseSignedCookie (C:\user\project
\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\utils.js:198:19).Please suggest solution.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mahahari Which version of Sails? + Post the `config/session.js` you are using.

Comment: iam using sails 0.9.16 version

Comment: // Uncomment the following lines to use your Mongo adapter as a session store
     adapter: 'mongo',
    
     host: 'localhost',
     port: 27017,
     db: 'sails',
     collection: 'sessions',
//     //For session expiry
//     cookie: {
//        maxAge: 120 // 1200,000 ms = 20 min
//     },
    
    // Optional Values:
    //
    // # Note: url will override other connection settings
    //url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/abcde/sessions',
    
     username: '',
     password: '',
     auto_reconnect: false,
     ssl: false,
     stringify: true